# Error in Elixir backend when trying to view network requests in chrome dev console

Tags: react-native, ecto, elixir

[As per this Github answer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/934#issuecomment-269811544) - I need to implement this line of code in react native in order to view my network requests in the chrome dev console:

```
GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest
```

But when I do, requests that I send to my localhost Elixir backend from my frontend, produce this error:

```
15:48:41.502 [error] #PID<0.406.0> running Api.Router terminated
Server: 192.168.20.3:4000 (http)
Request: GET /favicon.ico
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Api.Router.do_match/4
        (api) lib/api/router.ex:14: Api.Router.do_match(%Plug.Conn{adapter: {Plug.Adapters.
Cowboy.Conn, :...}, assigns: %{}, before_send: [], body_params: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect
: :body_params}, cookies: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :cookies}, halted: false, host: "192
.168.20.3", method: "GET", owner: #PID<0.406.0>, params: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :para
ms}, path_info: ["favicon.ico"], path_params: %{}, peer: {{192, 168, 20, 3}, 58348}, port:
4000, private: %{}, query_params: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :query_params}, query_string
: "", remote_ip: {192, 168, 20, 3}, req_cookies: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :cookies}, re
q_headers: [{"host", "192.168.20.3:4000"}, {"connection", "keep-alive"}, {"user-agent", "Mo
zilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome
/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"}, {"accept", "image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8"}, {"referer", "ht
tp://192.168.20.3:4000/categories"}, {"accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch"}, {"accept-l
anguage", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"}, {"origin", "http://evil.com/"}], request_path: "/f
avicon.ico", resp_body: nil, resp_cookies: %{}, resp_headers: [{"cache-control", "max-age=0
, private, must-revalidate"}], scheme: :http, script_name: [], secret_key_base: nil, state:
 :unset, status: nil}, "GET", ["favicon.ico"], "192.168.20.3")
        (api) lib/api/router.ex:1: Api.Router.plug_builder_call/2
        (api) lib/plug/debugger.ex:123: Api.Router.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade
/4
        (cowboy) /Users/Ben/Development/Projects/vepo/api/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.e
rl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

so The above line of code is doing something to my network requests that Elixir doesn't like. In the error it complains about `lib/api/router.ex:14` and `lib/api/router.ex:1` which is just:
 1: `defmodule Api.Router do`
14: `get "/" do`

Any help on the error appreciated.

**EDIT:** The error just occurs on the first path in `router.ex`. I deleted all paths except:

```
  get "/categories/" do
    Api.Repo.getCategories(conn)
  end
```

And now it happens on `get "/categories/" do`

**The main change in the code that the top line in the question does is it means I have to enable CORS which I did with a browser plugin so maybe Elixir doesn't like that.**

I added:

```
  get "/favicon.ico" do
    # Api.Repo.getCategories(conn)
  end
```

Now the error is this:

```
17:17:05.354 [error] #PID<0.370.0> running Api.Router terminated
Server: 192.168.20.3:4000 (http)
Request: OPTIONS /categories
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Api.Router.do_match/4
        (api) lib/api/router.ex:13: Api.Router.do_match(%Plug.Conn{adapter: {Plug.Adapters.
Cowboy.Conn, :...}, assigns: %{}, before_send: [], body_params: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect
: :body_params}, cookies: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :cookies}, halted: false, host: "192
.168.20.3", method: "OPTIONS", owner: #PID<0.370.0>, params: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :
params}, path_info: ["categories"], path_params: %{}, peer: {{192, 168, 20, 3}, 50258}, por
t: 4000, private: %{}, query_params: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :query_params}, query_str
ing: "", remote_ip: {192, 168, 20, 3}, req_cookies: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :cookies},
 req_headers: [{"host", "192.168.20.3:4000"}, {"connection", "keep-alive"}, {"access-contro
l-request-method", "GET"}, {"origin", "http://evil.com/"}, {"user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Mac
intosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110
 Safari/537.36"}, {"access-control-request-headers", "x-requested-with"}, {"accept", "*/*"}
, {"referer", "http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui"}, {"accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdc
h"}, {"accept-language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"}], request_path: "/categories", resp_
body: nil, resp_cookies: %{}, resp_headers: [{"cache-control", "max-age=0, private, must-re
validate"}], scheme: :http, script_name: [], secret_key_base: nil, state: :unset, status: n
il}, "OPTIONS", ["categories"], "192.168.20.3")
        (api) lib/api/router.ex:1: Api.Router.plug_builder_call/2
        (api) lib/plug/debugger.ex:123: Api.Router.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade
/4
        (cowboy) /Users/Ben/Development/Projects/vepo/api/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.e
rl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

**there is also this error over and over again:**

```
17:16:48.032 [error] GenServer #PID<0.332.0> terminating
** (stop) exited in: GenServer.call(Postgrex.TypeManager, {:get, Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Typ
eModule, {'localhost', 5432, "api_repo"}}, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) time out
    (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:737: GenServer.call/3
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:621: Postgrex.Protocol.bootstrap/3
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:475: Postgrex.Protocol.handshake/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:134: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol

17:16:48.032 [error] GenServer #PID<0.329.0> terminating
** (stop) exited in: GenServer.call(Postgrex.TypeManager, {:get, Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Typ
eModule, {'localhost', 5432, "api_repo"}}, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) time out
    (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:737: GenServer.call/3
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:621: Postgrex.Protocol.bootstrap/3
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:475: Postgrex.Protocol.handshake/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:134: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
```

Comment: That error is because of a request to `/favicon.ico`. You can either ignore it or add a `get "/favicon.ico"` that serves something.

Comment: ...or just put a `favicon.ico` icon file to the web root.

Comment: @Dogbert thanks! That error wasn't critical but there was a critical error because it no longer gets categories. I have posted a (hopefully) more helpful error to the bottom of my question.

Comment: @Dogbert and posted another error to the bottom of the question

Comment: @Dogbert I just added 

`options "/categories/" do
    Api.Repo.getCategories(conn)
  end` to `router.ex` and it now works. Cheers!